# URI not shown anymore for structures?

Tags: control-panel

In the entry list for structures, there used to be a column where my client could see the URI of each entry. Now that it dissapeared because of what seems to be the last update of Craft CMS, how can I bring it back? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each entry type, there is now an easy way to manage what columns are shown. From the admin, if you choose Entries from the main navigation, and then go to the entry type in question, you should see a small cog in the bottom left:

[image: Entry columns control]

Click that and you'll be shown a number of checkboxes with columns that can displayed. Click the URI checkbox to enable that column, and then click Save. You can also drag and drop the column names here to re-arrange them.

[image: URI column checkbox]

You should now see that column in the entry list:

[image: Entry list with URI column]

Comment: Perfect, too simple!